# Getting embedding lookup result from BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Prior to passing my tokens through BERT, I would like to perform some processing on their embeddings, (the result of the embedding lookup layer). The [HuggingFace BERT TensorFlow implementation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#tfbertmodel) allows us to access the output of embedding lookup using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertConfig, BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids = tf.constant(bert_tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True))[None, :]
attention_mask = tf.stack([tf.ones(shape=(len(sent),)) for sent in input_ids])
token_type_ids = tf.stack([tf.ones(shape=(len(sent),)) for sent in input_ids])

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=config)

result = bert_model(inputs={'input_ids': input_ids, 
                            'attention_mask': attention_mask, 
                            'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})
inputs_embeds = result[-1][0]  # output of embedding lookup
```

Subsequently, one can process `inputs_embeds` and then send this in as an input to the same model using:

```
inputs_embeds = process(inputs_embeds)  # some processing on inputs_embeds done here (dimensions kept the same)
result = bert_model(inputs={'inputs_embeds': inputs_embeds, 
                            'attention_mask': attention_mask, 
                            'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})
output = result[0]
```

where `output` now contains the output of BERT for the modified input. However, this requires two full passes through BERT. Instead of running BERT all the way through just to perform embedding lookup, I would like to just get the output of the embedding lookup layer. **Is this possible, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in fact incorrect to treat the first output `result[-1][0]` as the result of an embedding lookup. The raw embedding lookup is given by:

```
embeddings = bert_model.bert.get_input_embeddings()
word_embeddings = embeddings.word_embeddings
inputs_embeds = tf.gather(word_embeddings, input_ids)
```

while `result[-1][0]` gives the embedding lookup *plus* positional embeddings and token type embeddings. The above code does not require a full pass through BERT, and the result can be processed prior to feeding into the remaining layers of BERT.

**EDIT**: To get the result of addition positional and token type embeddings to an arbitrary `inputs_embeds`, one can use:

```
full_embeddings = embeddings(inputs=[None, None, token_type_ids, inputs_embeds])
```

Here, the `call` method for the `embeddings` object accepts a list which is fed into the `_embeddings` method. The first value is `input_ids`, the second `position_ids`, the third `token_type_ids`, and the fourth `inputs_embeds`. (See [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7b75aa9fa55bee577e2c7403301ed31103125a35/src/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.py#L133) for more details.) If you have multiple sentences in one input, you may need to set `position_ids`.